# R: Creatng DocumentTermMatrix from matrix (originally libsvm data)

Tags: r, nlp

I have term frequency data (cols:terms, rows:documents) stored in sparse data format.

I import and convert to matrix as follows:

```
rawmforCluster=read.matrix.csr(".\\jobDescription\\ReducedAndJoined.libsvm")
sparseforCluster=rawmforCluster$x
sparseMatrixforCluster=as.matrix(sparseforCluster)
```

This creates a matrix:

```
term1, term2, term3
1,     0,     2
2,     1,     0
0,     0,     1
```

(except 60000 rows and 400 columns)

I need to convert this matrix to a DocumentTermsMatrix so I can enter it into topicmodels LDA function

```
ap_lda <- LDA(sparseMatrixforCluster, k = 10, control = list(seed = 1234))
```

NOTE: I can enter the matrix in directly, but I get the following error when analyzing the results:

> tidy(ap_lda, matrix = "beta")
>
> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :
>
> Column `term` is of unsupported type NULL

Comment: Have you tried sth in the veins of `m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3);library(tm);dtm <- as.DocumentTermMatrix(m, weighting = weightTf)`?

Comment: I haven't. That may be the answer

Comment: The conversion worked but the tidy method still fails. Thanks a million. I will look into the issue further. I was probably barking up the wrong tree

Comment: dimnames of the DTM is null. So I probably just need to add colheads to the matrix